# How to profile a cdef function?

Tags: python, profiling, cython

I have an application that uses many `nogil` `cdef` function and I would like to profile them
in order to find the bottle-necks.

I tried passing the `profile=True` directive to Cython but these functions seem to be imune, such that the output of `cProfile.run()` contains the timings of the functions calling the `cdef` functions, but not of the `cdef` functions themselves.

Is there another directive or profiler that can be used in order to profile the `cdef` functions?

---

EDIT: [this is link to the application file that I am referring to...](https://github.com/compmech/compmech/blob/master/compmech/conecyl/clpt/clpt_donnell_bc1_nonlinear.pyx). In order to Profile you must set:

```
#cython: profile=True
```

at the header.

Comment: Why can't you just temporarily remove the `nogil`?

Comment: @Veedrac it took some time to remove all the `nogil`s, but even though the `cdef` functions are not detected by the profiler..., their corresponding time is included in the `def` function calling them

Comment: !. Are any Cython functions showing up?

Comment: @Veedrac sorry about the last comment. You are correct, removing the `nogil` AND setting `#cython: profile=True` solved the problem and the `cdef` functions appeared in the profiler. I would be happy to accept your answer if you posted it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The profiler needs the `gil`, so, with the help of the comments from @Veedrac, the solution was to:

- use only `cdef` functions without the `nogil` directive
- set `#cython: profile=True` at the header of the `.pyx` ([or somewhere else](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/profiling_tutorial.html))

The drawback here is that, by removing `nogil`, one can not use `prange` in order to profile the parallel execution. Another question remains... is it possible to profile a `nogil` function?